# Sort grouped series in SSRS Report

Tags: reporting-services, charts

I have a chart with a count of X per year per category, i.e.

```
X #####                       # 2012
X @@@@@@                      @ 2013
Y #############
Y @@
Z ###########
Z @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
```

How can I apply a sort to the 2013 values (but keep the grouping within X, Y, Z) - i.e. in this case, Z at the top, X mid and Y at the bottom, based on 2013 values.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, the trick is to name the Category Group and then use a sort expression on the Category Group. If you want to sort by values in 2013, use

```
=Sum(IIf(year(Fields!TradeDate.Value) = 2013, 
    CDbl(Fields![The field being summed].Value), CDbl(0)), 
    "[The Category Grouping Name]")
```

The Cdbl is required to ensure `Sum` is working on the same data types.

Answer (score 0):

I bet if you add row groups to your report By Year and By -Whatever XYZ Is- then you can sort your output by year while keeping the xyz grouping.